# jQuery selector based on deep children text content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

This is an example of HTML I am working with.

```
<html>
    <div class="parent-div">
        <ul>
            <li class="title">Color</li>
            <li>Red</li>
            <li class="title">Shape</li>
            <li>Squared</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</html>
```

I would like to convert the current HTML in the following list-item

- Color: Red
- Shape: Squared

And this is what I tried so far:

`$("html > div.parent-div > ul > li:contains('Color')")`

However it throws an exception:

> Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelectorAll' on
>   'Document': html > div.parent-div > ul > li:contains('Color')'
>   is not a valid selector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `html` is the same as `document`. Leave the html out of the selector.

```
$("div.parent-div > ul > li:contains('Color')")
```

The inner working of the *jQuery* is that it uses [`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll). Since document is the root, you don't need to specify it again inside the selector. If you do it will fail because HTML (document) doesn't contain an element called "HTML".

The following snippet will do what you desire.

```js
$("document").ready(function(){
  //select all the list elements with the class title
  $("div.parent-div > ul > li.title").each(function(){
    //concat the text of the title element and the next sibling into one string.
    var text = $(this).text() + ": " + $(this).next().text();
    $(this).html(text); //change the title element's html to set string
    $(this).next().detach(); //delete the value element from the DOM.
  })
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
    <div class="parent-div">
        <ul>
            <li class="title">Color</li>
            <li>Red</li>
            <li class="title">Shape</li>
            <li>Squared</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

no need to write `html` in `jQuery` selector

```
$("div.parent-div > ul > li:contains('Color')")
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know the reasoning of this, but you can get it with something like this:

```
var output = {};
var output_index = 0;
var last_title = "";

var allLi = $("#parent-div li");
var $this = null;

for(var i = 0; i < allLi.length; i++){
   $this = $(this);
   if($this).hasClass(title){
      last_title = $this.html();
   } else {
      output[last_title] = $this.html();
   }
})
```